# How to set basedir on a Jade project

Tags: pug

I'm using Jade for a project and I need to use absolute paths. Upon trying to use them, I encountered an error saying `the "basedir" option is required to use "include" with "absolute" paths`.

Thing is, I have no idea whatsoever where or how to set this option. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: to less information! how are you using jade? server side? how you are calling the API? you need to provide a code snippet.

Comment: try this `pug.compileFile(path, {basedir: __basedir})`, __basedir you can obtain from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67105949/7009215

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are using Express.js.

add the following line to your app

```
app.locals.basedir = path.join(__dirname, 'views');
```

Comment: I'm not. I solved it by making a .js file containing the basedir option and then calling it with "-O" through the command line when watching the file(s).

Answer (score 0):

It is important to mention that Pug is a template engine for Node.js and the browser. Which means that you can run Pug without Node.js. However, if you want to include or extend files using the absolute path, you need a `basedir`. This is defined using Node.js as follows:
`global.__basedir = __dirname`